# xfs fllesystem remount doesn't work when modify quota configure

Tags: linux, mount, xfs

1.At the begining

```
mount | grep home 
/dev/sdb1 on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

2.try to modify

```
mount -o remount,rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,prjquota  /dev/sbd1 /home
```

3.check it again

```
mount | grep home 
/dev/sdb1 on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

It doesn' work.

```
cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Aug  9 15:24:43 2016
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=8f1038a3-6c31-4ce1-a9ef-3d7325e10bef /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=c687eab8-3ddd-4756-b91e-ad562b522f7c /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=7ae72a46-1407-49e6-8669-95bb9e592794 /home                   xfs     rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,prjquota        0 0
UUID=3ccea12f-25d0-437b-9c4b-6ad6a9bd724c /tmp                    xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=b8ab4016-49bd-4f48-9620-5bda76f4d8b1 /var/log                xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=8b9a7ada-3f02-4ee5-8010-ad32a5d7461e swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

I can modify the `/etc/fstab` then restart machine make it work. But,is there any way I can change the quota configure without reboot?

Answer (score 1):

According to RHEL documentation you can't:

> XFS quotas are not a remountable option. The -o quota option must be
>   specified on the initial mount for quotas to be in effect.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch03s09.html#idp21353040

Also I tried changing a user (test) quota using:

```
xfs_quota -x /home
xfs_quota> report -hu
User quota on /home (/dev/mapper/cl_backup--server-home)
                        Blocks              
User ID      Used   Soft   Hard Warn/Grace   
---------- --------------------------------- 
root            0      0      0  00 [------]
test        11,4G     9G    10G  00 [-none-]

xfs_quota> limit bsoft=30g bhard=32g test
xfs_quota> report -hu
User quota on /home (/dev/mapper/cl_backup--server-home)
                        Blocks              
User ID      Used   Soft   Hard Warn/Grace   
---------- --------------------------------- 
root            0      0      0  00 [------]
test        11,4G    30G    32G  00 [------]

xfs_quota> q
```